# Flask CORS work only for first request, what's the bug in my code?

Tags: python, flask, cors, werkzeug, flask-cors

### background

1. There is a JS app serving at 127.0.0.1:8080, which refers some API serving at 127.0.0.1:5000 by a Flask app. [See FlaskCode]
2. When I open this js app in Chrome, first request work well and the second request ends with CORS problem, [see ChromeDebug1].
3. Additionally, I found this 'OPTIONS' is response as 405 (method not allow) in Flask output, and the output from flask_cors is not same like first request. [see FlaskOut].
4. I'm a newbee in FE and python, so if it is stupid bug, please let me know.
5. my env is

```
MacOs M1 version11.1
Chrome Version 87.0
Python 3.8.2
Flask 2.1.1
Werkzeug 2.1.1
```

### question

1. It seems that flask_cors works only once in my code, but what's wrong?
2. Look at the difference of first req and second req, seems that second reponse for 'OPTIONS' do not have headers `("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")`?
3. why firest request not have log like `flask_cors.extension:Request`

====== second edit =========

Thanks for David's advice. I used tcp dump to capture networking, [See wireshark]. This OPTION request is standard in my opinion. So, it lead me to question 4.

4. why flask print `"{"examinationOID":"61e8d2248373a7329e12f29b"}OPTIONS /yd/pass-through/get-examination HTTP/1.1" 405 -` while request not have body? Maybe printing is a trash object from last request which is not gc correctly, due to long connection and exception handling?

I have only one python file, and run it with `python ./demo2.py --log=INFO`

### appendix

#### FlaskCode

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

from flask import Flask
from flask import Response
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
import logging
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, supports_credentials=True)

demoDataPath="xxx"

@app.route("/yd/pass-through/get-examination", methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def getexamination():
    logging.getLogger('demo2').info('into getexamination')
    response = {}
    response["code"]=0
    response["message"]="good end"
    f = open(demoDataPath+"/rsp4getexamination.json", "r")
    response["data"]= json.loads(f.read())
    return Response(json.dumps(response), mimetype='application/json', status=200) 

@app.route("/yd/pass-through/report-config", methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def getconfig():
    logging.getLogger('demo2').info('into getconfig')
    response = {}
    response["code"]=0
    response["message"]="good end"
    f = open(demoDataPath+"/rsp4getreportconfig.json", "r")
    response["data"]= json.loads(f.read())
    return Response(json.dumps(response), mimetype='application/json', status=200) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger('flask_cors').level = logging.DEBUG
    logging.getLogger('werkzeug').level = logging.DEBUG
    logging.getLogger('demo2').level = logging.DEBUG
    app.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logging.info("app run")
    app.run(debug=True, threaded=True, port=5001)
```

#### ChromeDebug1

[image]

#### FlaskOut

```
DEBUG:flask_cors.core:CORS request received with 'Origin' http://127.0.0.1:8080
DEBUG:flask_cors.core:The request's Origin header matches. Sending CORS headers.
DEBUG:flask_cors.core:Settings CORS headers: MultiDict([('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://127.0.0.1:8080'), ('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'content-type, traceid, withcredentials'), ('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'DELETE, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, PUT'), ('Vary', 'Origin')])
DEBUG:flask_cors.extension:CORS have been already evaluated, skipping
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2022 20:33:36] "OPTIONS /yd/pass-through/report-config HTTP/1.1" 200 -
[2022-04-21 20:33:36,736] INFO in demo2: into getconfig
INFO:demo2:into getconfig
DEBUG:flask_cors.core:CORS request received with 'Origin' http://127.0.0.1:8080
DEBUG:flask_cors.core:The request's Origin header matches. Sending CORS headers.
DEBUG:flask_cors.core:Settings CORS headers: MultiDict([('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://127.0.0.1:8080'), ('Vary', 'Origin')])
DEBUG:flask_cors.extension:CORS have been already evaluated, skipping
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2022 20:33:36] "POST /yd/pass-through/report-config HTTP/1.1" 200 -
DEBUG:flask_cors.extension:Request to '/yd/pass-through/get-examination' matches CORS resource '/*'. Using options: {'origins': ['.*'], 'methods': 'DELETE, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, PUT', 'allow_headers': ['.*'], 'expose_headers': None, 'supports_credentials': True, 'max_age': None, 'send_wildcard': False, 'automatic_options': True, 'vary_header': True, 'resources': '/*', 'intercept_exceptions': True, 'always_send': True}
DEBUG:flask_cors.core:CORS request received with 'Origin' http://127.0.0.1:8080
DEBUG:flask_cors.core:The request's Origin header matches. Sending CORS headers.
DEBUG:flask_cors.core:Settings CORS headers: MultiDict([('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://127.0.0.1:8080'), ('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true'), ('Vary', 'Origin')])
DEBUG:flask_cors.extension:CORS have been already evaluated, skipping
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2022 20:33:36] "{"examinationOID":"61e8d2248373a7329e12f29b"}OPTIONS /yd/pass-through/get-examination HTTP/1.1" 405 -
```

#### wireshark

[image]

Comment: What happens when you make the same request with Firefox or Safari instead? (I mean what happens when you use the same configuration shown in the question here, not the workaround in your answer.) I think you’ll likely have the same problem — which would mean it’s not a bug in Chrome at least.

Comment: I’m guessing that the `"{"examinationOID":"61e8d2248373a7329e12f29b"}OPTIONS` thing is caused by werkzeug itself, and that if you remove werkzeug, that won’t happen any longer.

Comment: The Wireshark log shown in https://i.stack.imgur.com/JumcF.png seems to indicate that Chrome is sending a normal `OPTIONS` request as expected — not a broken `"{"examinationOID":"61e8d2248373a7329e12f29b"}OPTIONS` request. Thus, something on the server side must be introducing that `"{"examinationOID":"61e8d2248373a7329e12f29b"}OPTIONS` oddness — most likely werkzeug, it seems.

Comment: @sideshowbarker Thanks for your advice. Safari not work and error the same way. So I think there is something wrong with my flask code. I use venv as flask runtime, would that matter?

Comment: I don’t think using a venv would be a problem. The much more likely cause seems to be werkzeug. So you could try to isolate it by removing werkzeug and see if that makes the error go away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was getting a similar error:
`param1=value1&param2=value2GET /css/base.css HTTP/1.1`
where the leading params are from a POST request called just before. Setting `threaded=False` (as @david-k-hess suggested) helped.

### The whole story was:

- Browser submits a form using POST
- Flask server responds with a web page
- The web page contains `/css/base.css` in its head
- Browser downloads `/css/base.css` using GET
- Flask server returns HTTP 405 because it thinks the method is `param1=value1&param2=value2GET`

## Fix

Fix 1 suggested by @david-k-hess: In Flask `app.run()`, add `threaded=False`

Fix 2: It also seems that the problem was fixed by upgrading Flask and Werkzeug to 2.1.2

## My environment:

- Python 3.9
- Flask 2.1.1
- Werkzeug 2.1.1

Other than that, my venv contains:

- Jinja2
- MarkupSafe
- click
- colorama
- importlib-metadata
- itsdangerous
- pip
- setuptools
- wheel
- zipp

Comment: Ah, so then looks like Werkzeug had a threading bug and it was fixed in 2.1.2. Might be worth confirming that with them in case the bug is just masked for now.

Comment: HOLY DUDE! I was going nuts with this, can't believe I spent hours trying to figure out what was causing this, in my case it was happening just for a particular endpoint, which makes no sense at all. I upgraded my flask and werkzeug to version 2.1.2 and everything worked as supposed to, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I solve my problem with another "bug" like following. And I still have no idea why my code not work as flask_cors document saied. If you have better solution or advice, please let me know.

```py
@app.after_request
def add_headers(response):
    response.headers.add('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'content-type, traceid, withcredentials')
    response.status=200
    logging.getLogger('demo2').info('into add_headers')
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be here:

```
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2022 20:33:36] "{"examinationOID":"61e8d2248373a7329e12f29b"}OPTIONS /yd/pass-through/get-examination HTTP/1.1" 405 -
```

Compare that to:

```
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2022 20:33:36] "OPTIONS /yd/pass-through/report-config HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

It is trying to use an invalid HTTP method of `{"examinationOID":"61e8d2248373a7329e12f29b"}OPTIONS` instead of just plain `OPTIONS`.

It seems like something is corrupting your CORS headers and confusing Chrome into doing that. A likely source of that would be the Flask-CORS configuration. Is there some setup elsewhere that you haven't shown us? Or is it just using default configuration?

If it is just default, then it would help to see the Javascript code running in Chrome - that might be causing the corrupted method from the first request to the second.

Also, in your chrome dev tools screenshot, you are filtering on 'XHR' - that won't show the OPTIONS requests which will help you figure out what's going wrong. They are shown under 'Other'.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, and I provided more detail in this question. These detail should cover suspicious place in your description. If you are interested in, it's helpful for more advice.

Comment: What happens if you use `threaded=False` in the .run() call?

Comment: And if you provide some frontend Javascript code so that others can recreate this it will help.

Comment: Sure, I can provide whole code base to you, if you want. But I think tcpdump is enough for us to see the behavior of front end and back end.

Comment: What happens if you use threaded=False in the .run() call?

Comment: Hi @DavidK.Hess, I'm getting a similar error: `param1=value1&param2=value2GET /css/base.css HTTP/1.1` where the leading params are from a POST request called just before. Setting `threaded=False` helped. Thanks

Comment: Ah ha. So, there appears to be a bug in Werkzeug related to enabling threading. May want to report that to them at https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues